# count the number of models with a certain Enum value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to get the number of models with a certain enum value.
Something like this:

```
  (@Model.Status == "pending").Count().tostring())
```

or

```
  (@Model.Status.Contains("pending").Count().tostring())
```

All the Models are passed back originally, and are then grouped by their status.
For example `@Model.Count()`  will return all models (pending, accepted etc.)

To put into context, this count will just appear as a number on an inbox, so the end result would look like:

> Pending (8) Accepted (3)....etc

Please note this is an asp.net MVC 4 app using razor 2 views.

Answer (score 2):

You can use overloaded `Count` method:

```
@Model.Count(m => m.Satus == YourEnum.Pending)
```

Comment: it's never that straight forward, long winded explanation below,cheers

Answer (score 1):

To count on a specific condition, you must use a predicate inside the [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) method, like this :

```
(@Model.Count(s => s.Status == StatusEnum.Pending).ToString())
```

Also, if you only have your enum name in `string` form, you will need to use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/essfb559.aspx) to get the value, like this :

```
(StatusEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(StatusEnum), "Pending")
```

The result will be :

```
(@Model.Count(s => s.Status == (StatusEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(StatusEnum), "Pending")).ToString())
```

Comment: It's never that straight forward, my class containing the model has the following in relation to the enum...public ReferralInteractionMode(ReferralStatus status), this is in its own class where Referral status is my Enum, which includes switch statements, and a number of public bool who's values are determined by the cases in the switch statement....so has a result I can't complete this line   @Model.Count(m => m.Status == ?   because I'm using a different model, is it good practice to include another model ?? or is there another way ....